# display user data using django for loop

Tags: html, django, for-loop, django-forms

After a lot of time and effort, I have a menu header where the user can select their details that are to appear in their menu header.

I have set up the menu to be broken into 3 columns if the user has selected to display more than 20 menu items (**3 menu items are always displayed, so I have placed the column break on loop 17**).

If the user has selected less than 17 menu items the menu will be displayed across 2 columns like so:

[image]

If the user has selected more than 17 menu items the menu will be displayed across 3 columns.

When I attempt to place the column break at loop 17, **when there are exactly 17 menu entries**, the 3rd column is displayed, but I only want 2 columns. The 3 columns should only be displayed when there are **more than 17 menu options** selected.

Here is what I have with my current code:

[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I have tried exhaustively to fix this and cannot. I have made an error somewhere but I just cannot see it (I am embarrased that I have to post this question in order to solve my issue).

I am unsure if my HTML code is placed incorrectly or my django loop is calibrated incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mega-menu-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row equal-height">
            <div class="{% if selected_menu_entries|replace_comma_with_linespace|wordcount > 18 %}col-md-4{% else %}col-md-6{% endif %} equal-height-in">
                <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">

                    <!-- a Details Pages -->
                    {# 1st Menu Details are always available. #}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'a_details' %}">
                            {% trans "1st Menu" %}
                            <span class="badge rounded-2x badge-blue">
                                {{ a_details_count }}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- End a Details Pages -->

                    <!-- b Details Pages -->
                    {# 2nd Menu Details are always available. #}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'b_details' %}">
                            {% trans "2nd Menu" %}
                            <span class="badge rounded-2x badge-blue">
                                {{ b_details_count }}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- End b Details Pages -->

                    <!-- c Details Pages -->
                    {# 3rd menu  Details are always available. #}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'c_details' %}">
                            {% trans "3rd Menu" %}
                            <span class="badge rounded-2x badge-blue">
                                {{ c_details_count }}
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- End c Details Pages -->

                    <!-- remaining selected Menu Details Pages -->
                    {# Only display the Menu Details that the user has selected to appear. #}
                    {% for entry, count, view_link in test_menu %}

                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ view_link }}">
                                {{ entry.label }}
                                <span class="badge rounded-2x badge-blue">
                                    {{ count }}
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        {% ifequal forloop.counter 7 %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="{% if selected_menu_entries|replace_comma_with_linespace|wordcount > 18 %}col-md-4{% else %}col-md-6{% endif %} equal-height-in">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                        {% endifequal %}

                        {% ifequal forloop.counter 17 %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="{% if selected_menu_entries|replace_comma_with_linespace|wordcount > 18 %}col-md-4{% else %}col-md-6{% endif %} equal-height-in">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
                        {% endifequal %}

                    {% if forloop.last %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**I am hoping that someone can point out my mistake.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
{% ifequal forloop.counter 17 %}
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="{% if selected_menu_entries|replace_comma_with_linespace|wordcount > 18 %}col-md-4{% else %}col-md-6{% endif %} equal-height-in">
     <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
 {% endifequal %}
```

with:

```
{% ifequal forloop.counter 17 %}
{% if not forloop.last %}
 </ul>
  </div>
   <div class="{% if selected_menu_entries|replace_comma_with_linespace|wordcount > 18 %}col-md-4{% else %}col-md-6{% endif %} equal-height-in">
   <ul class="list-unstyled equal-height-list">
 {% endif %}
{% endifequal %}
```

Comment: Geo Jacob - Thank you. I can see from your code where I went wrong. Thanks again.